# Zepto page transitions will not work if i load jquery

Tags: jquery, transition, zepto

I use [this](https://github.com/dgileadi/zepto-page-transitions)

For page transitions. But if i load a jquery.js the transition.min.js giving a error.

Uncaught TypeError: $(...).transition is not a function

the lines in the is transition.min.js:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

$(document.body).transition('init').show();
});
```

Can anyone here help in my further?
thanks

Answer (score 0):

It's unadvisable to load both Zepto and jQuery. They are most likely conflicting with each other. Both libraries use the `$` as a special character. If you must use both, look into [jQuery noConflict mode](https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/avoid-conflicts-other-libraries/)

Comment: Thanls for your answer. but Zepto gives no errors. Only transition.min.js giva a error.